# Can't input Japanese in WebView on Android 4.0.x?

Tags: android, webview

I have a `HTML` file. And I used `WebView` to load this `HTML` file. After, the cursor appear on `WebView`, but I can't input Japanese or even I can't swap other keyboard as number keyboard. But if the `HTML` file has content in Japanese, It can display normal. The bug appear on `Android 4.0.x`, but `4.1.x` or over don't have this bug.

This is my `HTML` file that I had created

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>ZSSRichTextEditor</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ZSSRichTextEditor.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body onLoad="zss_editor.init();">
  <div id="zss_editor_content" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; overflow: auto;" contenteditable="true" ></div>
  <div id="zss_editor_footer"> </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And on a html page you did not create? And in the built in browser?

Comment: I had created HTML file, I have updated my question above, thanks

Comment: I am saying, have you tried with a page you did not create? In addition have you tried on the built in browser?

Comment: Oh sorry, I am wrong understand your meaning. I had tested on default browser of Android. I load w3schools and go to "Try It Yourself", after I add `<div contenteditable="true"></div>"`, and then tap "See Result". The windows in right side appear cursor but can not input. It just on Android 4.0. I am still finding document on google to see this is the bug of `WebView` or not.